# Can Chrome browser retrieve visitor's UDID or Serial Number on Mac?

Tags: html, macos, security, browser, udid

After I log in to appleid.apple.com, I found Apple has a log for the serial number of my Mac. So is it possible to retrieve visitor's UDID or Serial Number from Chrome browser on a Mac?
If possible, how to do it?

Comment: A website on the Internet is not connected to your LAN and will not be able to determine your MAC address.

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami They're talking about Macintosh computers, not MAC addresses.

Comment: There's something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915847/get-an-iphone-udid-from-mobile-safari but that's mostly focussed on iOS (where it is (was?) possible if a user installs something), not sure it still works, or works on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Apple has that information because you registered your device, not because the browser sends it.

That page shows information about all your registered Apple devices, not specifically the one you are logging in with.

Comment: How about Safari browser? I have done some searches, it seems Safari can check the UDID on Mac..